# Extraer parte de un texto con expresión regular PHP

Tags: php, regex

Tengo este texto `"30:10"`,
y quisiera extraer el 30 y luego el 10 mediante una expresión regular.

No deseo usar  `explode(":"...)` porque tendría que crear una variable,
quiero obtener directamente el 30 o el 10.

Anotaciones:

Tengo esta función:
`sumar($numero1,$numero2){}`,
y cuando reciba 10:20 quiero sumar esos 2 números.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué prefieres una expresión regular? Aparte de ser más lento que `explode()` también se crea una variable para obtener las coincidencias y el manejo es muy similar con ambas opciones.

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar?

Comment: si amigo, gracias por la ayuda, marque tu respuesta como respuesta correcta.
gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar directamente:

- **(.*)** : Esto hace un match de cualquier caracter.
- **(\d+)**: Hace un match de digitos del 0-9.

Usaré, por ejemplo (.*), los paréntesis capturan grupos de caracteres. Por lo que capturará lo que esté entre los primeros paréntesis, y lo que estén en los segundos paréntesis. Y podremos tenerlo en un array.

**Código**:

```
<?php

$expresion_regular = '/(.*):(.*)/';
$string = '30:10';

preg_match_all($expresion_regular, $string, $resultado, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0); #, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($resultado);
```

**Resultado**:

```
> php regex.php 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "30:10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "30"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

Luego podrás acceder a ellos, por ejemplo:

**Código**

```
var_dump($resultado[0][1]);
```

**Resultado**:

```
string(2) "30"
```

Puedes convertirlos a int si lo ves necesario.

Comment: Excelente amigo, gracias !!

Comment: Amigo lo estoy provando y me sale como primera coincidencia array[0] todo el texto ...

Comment: Sí tienes que acceder al primer elemento [0] y luego al que necesites sea 1 o 2, por ejemplo: $resultado[0][1] o $resultado[0][2]. Con el var_dump puedes ver la posición